# Hausdorff space with a additional property

Tags: general-topology

Suppose a Hausdorff topological space $(X, \tau)$ has the following property. A and B are disjoint closed subsets of $X$ implies there is a continuous function say $f_{AB} : X \rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $f(x)=0$ if $x \in A$ and $f(x)=1$if $x \in B$, then $(X, \tau)$ is a normal space. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Look at preimages $f^{-1}(1/2,1]$ and $f^{-1}[0,1/2)$. Recall what normality means.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $\left[0,\frac13\right)$ and $\left(\frac23,1\right]$ are disjoint open sets in $[0,1]$.